# Add an object inside another object in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to build a simple app where I can add people to a party.How can I achieve that through a separate text input & button so I can add a person in the user array which is inside the party object.
I somehow achieved that but I made it like in the same button that adds the party so I can only add one user to it .
Would appreciate some suggestions and help ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  List,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";

import Badge from "react-bootstrap/Badge";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import Task from "./components/task";
//import Task from './components/task';

export default function App() {
  const [partyTitle, setPartyName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [userName, setUser] = useState("");


  const [parties, setParties] = useState([
    { partyName: "Party 1", description: " test", id: 0,date:"12.01.2022",
    users:[
      {id:0,
        name:'John'}] },
  ]);

  const handleAddButtonClick = () => {
    setParties((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        partyName: partyTitle, // change
        description: description,
        id: parties.length,
        date:date,
        users:[{
            id:1,
            name:userName

        }]
      },
    ]);
    setPartyName(null);
    setDescription(null);
    setDate(null);
  };



  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Added this scroll view to enable scrolling when list gets longer than the page */}
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
        }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      >
        {/* Today's Tasks */}
        <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Upcoming parties</Text>
          <View style={styles.items}>
            {/* This is where the tasks will go! */}

            {parties.map((item, index) => {
              
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={index}
                  // onPress={() => completeTask(index)}
                >
                 
                  <Task name={item.partyName} description={item.description} date={item.date}></Task>

                  {item.users.map((user, index) => (
                  <View key={index}>
                    <Text>Users: {user.name}</Text>
                      </View>
                    ))}

                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

      {/* Write a task */}
      {/* Uses a keyboard avoiding view which ensures the keyboard does not cover the items on screen */}
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "column",
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={"Write a name"}
            value={partyTitle}
            onChangeText={setPartyName}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={"Write a date"}
            value={description}
            onChangeText={setDescription}
          />
           <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={"Write a date"}
            value={date}
            onChangeText={setDate}
          />
           <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={"Write user"}
            value={userName}
            onChangeText={setUser}
          />
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddButtonClick()}>
          <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code going to help you to restrict adding User into Users array if User name is already in Party User List.

```
const handleAddButtonClick = () => {
    const isOldUser = false

    Parties.users.filter((user,index)=>{
       if(name === userName){
           isOldUser = true
       }
    })


    !isOldUser && setParties((prev) => [
      ...prev,
     {
        partyName: partyTitle, // change
        description: description,
        id: parties.length,
        date:date,
        users:[{
            id:1,
            name:userName

        }]
      },
    ]);
    setPartyName(null);
    setDescription(null);
    setDate(null);
  };
```